# Poetry: Disabling SSL certification check

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm trying to disable SSL certification check for self-signed certificate using example mentioned in : https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#certificates

```
poetry config certificates.foo.cert false
```

My repository is "private-pypi", so I am using `poetry config certificates.private-pypi.cert false`

But it seems that the value is getting "false" assigned as a string instead of boolean.

[image]

See the difference between the first and the second config, where the second config does not have `"` in the value.

How do I set it as such is should be assigned as boolean instead?

Comment: If upgrading is an option, this doesn't seem to be an issue for `poetry 1.2.2` and `poetry-core 1.3.2`

Comment: I' using poetry 1.3.1 and still encounter the issue above

Comment: Was there already an existing value that you are overwriting, or was that config value not present in the file? And can you add the version of poetry core you're using to help with reproducing the issue?